# AudioDeviceCallback returns connected WearOS watch as AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I'm working on functionality that detects currently active audio output device. I'm using `AudioManager`'s `registerAudioDeviceCallback` method for that. The problem I'm facing is that it returns my WearOS device that is currently connected to the phone as one of the possible audio outputs:
[image]

It is being detected as `TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO` and looks for me just like any Bluetooth headphones. Obviously, the watch doesn't work the same as headphones, so is there a way to somehow filter it out from the results? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to find corresponding `BluetoothDevice` for `AudioDeviceInfo` within [`BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#getBondedDevices()) using [`AudioDeviceInfo.getAddress()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo#getAddress()) and then look at [`BluetoothClass.getDeviceClass()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass#getDeviceClass()) to determine device class.
Kotlin example:

```
/**
 * Attempts to determine if the BLUETOOTH device is a wearable device that was mistakenly treated as an audio output.
 * if any attempt fails, returns true
 */
fun isAudioDevice(audioDeviceInfo: AudioDeviceInfo, bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager): Boolean {
    val nonAudioDeviceBluetoothClasses = listOf(
        BluetoothClass.Device.COMPUTER_DESKTOP,
        BluetoothClass.Device.COMPUTER_HANDHELD_PC_PDA,
        BluetoothClass.Device.COMPUTER_LAPTOP,
        BluetoothClass.Device.COMPUTER_PALM_SIZE_PC_PDA,
        BluetoothClass.Device.COMPUTER_SERVER,
        BluetoothClass.Device.COMPUTER_UNCATEGORIZED,
        BluetoothClass.Device.COMPUTER_WEARABLE,
        BluetoothClass.Device.HEALTH_BLOOD_PRESSURE,
        BluetoothClass.Device.HEALTH_DATA_DISPLAY,
        BluetoothClass.Device.HEALTH_GLUCOSE,
        BluetoothClass.Device.HEALTH_PULSE_OXIMETER,
        BluetoothClass.Device.HEALTH_PULSE_RATE,
        BluetoothClass.Device.HEALTH_THERMOMETER,
        BluetoothClass.Device.HEALTH_UNCATEGORIZED,
        BluetoothClass.Device.HEALTH_WEIGHING,
        BluetoothClass.Device.PERIPHERAL_KEYBOARD,
        BluetoothClass.Device.PERIPHERAL_KEYBOARD_POINTING,
        BluetoothClass.Device.PERIPHERAL_NON_KEYBOARD_NON_POINTING,
        BluetoothClass.Device.PERIPHERAL_POINTING,
        BluetoothClass.Device.PHONE_CELLULAR,
        BluetoothClass.Device.PHONE_CORDLESS,
        BluetoothClass.Device.PHONE_ISDN,
        BluetoothClass.Device.PHONE_MODEM_OR_GATEWAY,
        BluetoothClass.Device.PHONE_SMART,
        BluetoothClass.Device.PHONE_UNCATEGORIZED,
        BluetoothClass.Device.TOY_CONTROLLER,
        BluetoothClass.Device.TOY_DOLL_ACTION_FIGURE,
        BluetoothClass.Device.TOY_GAME,
        BluetoothClass.Device.TOY_ROBOT,
        BluetoothClass.Device.TOY_UNCATEGORIZED,
        BluetoothClass.Device.TOY_VEHICLE,
        BluetoothClass.Device.WEARABLE_GLASSES,
        BluetoothClass.Device.WEARABLE_HELMET,
        BluetoothClass.Device.WEARABLE_JACKET,
        BluetoothClass.Device.WEARABLE_PAGER,
        BluetoothClass.Device.WEARABLE_UNCATEGORIZED,
        BluetoothClass.Device.WEARABLE_WRIST_WATCH,
    )
    val address = audioDeviceInfo.address
    val bluetoothDevice = bluetoothManager.adapter.bondedDevices.find { it.address == address }
    return nonAudioDeviceBluetoothClasses.contains(bluetoothDevice?.bluetoothClass?.deviceClass).not()
}
```

Though that solution is more a workaround and might be unreliable on its own. I also suggest to look at [`AudioDeviceInfo.getCommunicationDevice()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#getCommunicationDevice()) (Added in API level 31) or [`mediaRouter.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRouter#getSelectedRoute(int)). I doubt that WearOS device will ever be there.